# My textures appear too dark when in the material tab viewport

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, 3d-view, texture-painting

The texture looks darker in the viewport compared to how it actually looks which u can see in the tab to the left. There's not a huge difference but u can see the contrast with the white. I would like to make it so the proper colour comes up in the viewport instead of this darker version. I have just switched over from blender 2.79 where the the colour in the viewport was the same as the actual texture.(using cycles)[image]

Comment: so what happens if you increase the light strength?

Comment: @moonboots it doesnt make a difference:/ it doesnt really matter tho, im getting used to it

Comment: maybe pack your images and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: sure, i deleted that file so ill send sumn else cos its like that for everything i have